# Is there a way to get my Apple Watch App to vibrate when the screen sleeps?

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui, watchos, haptic-feedback

I own a Apple Watch series 3 and I made an app for it that vibrates every specified amount of seconds. I know haptics drain your battery but, regardless, its the purpose of my app. I tried to test it on my watch and I encountered a problem. When the screen is on the app functions like its supposed to but as soon as I put my wrist down and the screen sleeps, the app runs in the background but it doesn't vibrate like supposed to. Is there a way around this? Like I said I have a series 3 therefore I don't have access to the always on screen display function.
My app code is below:

```
import SwiftUI
    

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var timerScreenShown = false
    @State var timeVal = 10
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            Text("Select \(timeVal)s intervals").padding()

            Picker(
                selection: $timeVal,
                label: Text("")){
                    ForEach(10...120, id: \.self) {
                        Text("\($0)")
                    }
                }
            
            NavigationLink(destination: SecondView(timerScreenShown: $timerScreenShown, timeVal: timeVal), isActive: $timerScreenShown, label: {Text("Go")})
            
        }
    }
}

struct SecondView: View{
    @Binding var timerScreenShown:Bool
    @State var timeVal = 10
    @State var startVal = 0
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            if timeVal > 0 {
                Text("Timer")
                    .font(.system(size: 14))
                Text("\(startVal)")
                    .font(.system(size: 40))
                    .onAppear(){
                        Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 1.0, repeats: true) { _ in
                            if self.timeVal > 0{
                                self.startVal += 1
                                if self.timeVal == self.startVal{
                                    
                                    WKInterfaceDevice.current().play(.failure)
                                    
                                    self.startVal = 0
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                Text("seconds")
                    .font(.system(size: 14))
                Button(action: {
                    self.timerScreenShown = false
                }) {
                    Text("Cancel")
                        .foregroundColor(.red)
                }
            } else {
                Button(action: {
                    self.timerScreenShown = false
                }) {
                    Text("Done")
                        .foregroundColor(.green)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        Group {
            ContentView()
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Use some other methods like notifications. `Timer` does not survive background well

Comment: Okay! Will look into that, thank you!